# ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with out-of-range integer to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to make a binary classifier, to check if an image is a letter or not. I've created the required dataset, and made a basic model to start, but I'm getting this error -

```
ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with out-of-range integer to Tensor.
```

Looked it up, as saw that it could happen if the data was in different dtypes, but eve after converting it all to float64, the error persists.

Do you have any clue as to why this might be?

```
norm_train_x, y_ = emnist.extract_training_samples('letters')
norm_test_x, y__ = emnist.extract_test_samples('letters')

norm_train_y = np.array([1] * len(norm_train_x))
norm_test_y = np.array([1] * len(norm_test_x))

norm_train_x = np.reshape(norm_train_x, (norm_train_x.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
norm_test_x = np.reshape(norm_test_x, (norm_test_x.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
```

My target is to create a classifier to identify whether an image is a letter or not, so I'm creating a dataset with imgs and random lines, denoted with respective labels being 1s and 0s.

Here's the code to load all the data and prepare for final use. I've stored all the random images in two folders.

```
def load_data():
  random_train_x = []
  for x in range(len(norm_train_x)):
    im = cv2.imread(r'/content/random_train_imgs/img_' + str(x) + '.png')
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im = np.reshape(im, (28, 28, 1))
    random_train_x.append(im)

  random_train_x = np.array(random_train_x)
  random_train_y = np.array([0] * len(random_train_x))

  print(random_train_x.shape, random_train_y.shape)

  random_test_x = []
  for x in range(len(norm_test_x)):
    im = cv2.imread(r'/content/random_test_imgs/img_' + str(x) + '.png')
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im = np.reshape(im, (28, 28, 1))
    random_test_x.append(im)

  random_test_x = np.array(random_test_x)
  random_test_y = np.array([0] * len(random_test_x))

  print(random_test_x.shape, random_test_y.shape)

  return (random_train_x, random_train_y), (random_test_x, random_test_y)


def finalise_data():
  global random_train_x, random_train_y, random_test_x, random_test_y
  global norm_train_X, norm_test_x, norm_train_y, norm_test_y

  train_x = np.concatenate((random_train_x, norm_train_x), axis=0)
  test_x = np.concatenate((random_test_x, norm_test_x), axis=0)
  train_y = np.concatenate((random_train_y, norm_train_y), axis=0)
  test_y = np.concatenate((random_test_y, norm_test_y), axis=0)

  test_shuffle = np.random.permutation(len(test_y))
  train_shuffle = np.random.permutation(len(train_y))

  train_x, train_y = train_x[train_shuffle], train_y[train_shuffle]
  test_x, test_y = test_x[test_shuffle], test_y[test_shuffle]

  print(train_x.shape, train_y.shape)
  print(test_x.shape, test_y.shape)

  return (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y)

train_x = train_x.astype('float32')
train_y = train_y.astype('float32')
test_x = test_x.astype('float32')
test_y = test_y.astype('float32')
```

The model architecture

```
model = models.Sequential([
                           layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28, 1]),
                           layers.Dense(28**28, activation='relu'),
                           layers.Dense(3)
])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), epochs=10)
```

The complete traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-761e0b4a48eb> in <module>()
      2                            layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28, 1]),
      3                            layers.Dense(28**28, activation='relu'),
----> 4                            layers.Dense(3)
      5 ])
      6 model.summary()

31 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    132         layers = [layers]
    133       for layer in layers:
--> 134         self.add(layer)
    135 
    136   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    215       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
    216       # refresh its output.
--> 217       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    218       if len(tf.nest.flatten(output_tensor)) != 1:
    219         raise ValueError(SINGLE_LAYER_OUTPUT_ERROR_MSG)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    975     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    976       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 977                                                 input_list)
    978 
    979     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1113       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1114       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1115           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1116 
   1117       if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    846       return tf.nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    847     else:
--> 848       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    849 
    850   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    884           # overridden).
    885           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
--> 886           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    887           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
    888           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   2657         # operations.
   2658         with tf_utils.maybe_init_scope(self):
-> 2659           self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
   2660       # We must set also ensure that the layer is marked as built, and the build
   2661       # shape is stored since user defined build functions may not be calling

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
   1183         constraint=self.kernel_constraint,
   1184         dtype=self.dtype,
-> 1185         trainable=True)
   1186     if self.use_bias:
   1187       self.bias = self.add_weight(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint, use_resource, synchronization, aggregation, **kwargs)
    661         synchronization=synchronization,
    662         aggregation=aggregation,
--> 663         caching_device=caching_device)
    664     if regularizer is not None:
    665       # TODO(fchollet): in the future, this should be handled at the

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _add_variable_with_custom_getter(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, getter, overwrite, **kwargs_for_getter)
    816         dtype=dtype,
    817         initializer=initializer,
--> 818         **kwargs_for_getter)
    819 
    820     # If we set an initializer and the variable processed it, tracking will not

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in make_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, trainable, caching_device, validate_shape, constraint, use_resource, collections, synchronization, aggregation, partitioner)
    127       synchronization=synchronization,
    128       aggregation=aggregation,
--> 129       shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
    130 
    131 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    264   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    265     if cls is VariableV1:
--> 266       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    267     elif cls is Variable:
    268       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in _variable_v1_call(cls, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, expected_shape, import_scope, constraint, use_resource, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
    225         synchronization=synchronization,
    226         aggregation=aggregation,
--> 227         shape=shape)
    228 
    229   def _variable_v2_call(cls,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in <lambda>(**kwargs)
    203                         shape=None):
    204     """Call on Variable class. Useful to force the signature."""
--> 205     previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
    206     for _, getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    207       previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in default_variable_creator(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2624         synchronization=synchronization,
   2625         aggregation=aggregation,
-> 2626         shape=shape)
   2627   else:
   2628     return variables.RefVariable(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    268       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    269     else:
--> 270       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    271 
    272 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def, import_scope, constraint, distribute_strategy, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
   1611           aggregation=aggregation,
   1612           shape=shape,
-> 1613           distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
   1614 
   1615   def _init_from_args(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, distribute_strategy, shape)
   1738           with ops.name_scope("Initializer"), device_context_manager(None):
   1739             if init_from_fn:
-> 1740               initial_value = initial_value()
   1741             if isinstance(initial_value, trackable.CheckpointInitialValue):
   1742               self._maybe_initialize_trackable()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/initializers_v2.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype, **kwargs)
    515     else:
    516       limit = math.sqrt(3.0 * scale)
--> 517       return self._random_generator.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit, dtype)
    518 
    519   def get_config(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/initializers_v2.py in random_uniform(self, shape, minval, maxval, dtype)
    971       op = tf.random.uniform
    972     return op(
--> 973         shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
    974 
    975   def truncated_normal(self, shape, mean, stddev, dtype):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py in random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed, name)
    294     maxval = 1
    295   with ops.name_scope(name, "random_uniform", [shape, minval, maxval]) as name:
--> 296     shape = tensor_util.shape_tensor(shape)
    297     # In case of [0,1) floating results, minval and maxval is unused. We do an
    298     # `is` comparison here since this is cheaper than isinstance or  __eq__.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in shape_tensor(shape)
   1078       # not convertible to Tensors because of mixed content.
   1079       shape = tuple(map(tensor_shape.dimension_value, shape))
-> 1080   return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
   1081 
   1082 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    344                                          as_ref=False):
    345   _ = as_ref
--> 346   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    347 
    348 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    270   """
    271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 
    274 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with out-of-range integer to Tensor.
```

Comment: Maybe share a snippet of code, it will be a lot easier to help you with some context. 
Also - check what the maximum value in this sequence is.

Comment: its happen when you data is biger than integer can handel

Comment: @gshpychka I've added a few lines of code

Comment: I don't see any code in the question, are you sure you applied the edit?

Comment: @gshpychka just did it

Comment: Right. Which line is causing the error? Specifying that will make it easier to help you.

Comment: I have no clue why the error is popping up, but the error message highlights the final layer of the model architecture.

Comment: The traceback always points to a specific line that triggers it. Maybe post the entire traceback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236120/discussion-between-just-another-beginner-and-gshpychka).

Comment: Error is due to integer value which is bigger value than given list/array. Out-of-range error clearly says something you are trying to access which is beyond the length of list. Thanks!